# I can't create my custom spring-boot starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-starter

I try to create `spring-boot-starter`. I create a simple `spring-boot module` with this Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'my.domain'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor"
}
```

And one class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiSpringBootStarterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiSpringBootStarterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

It builds successfully. But if I delete `ApiSpringBootStarterApplication`  class I get an error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':api-spring-boot-starter:bootJar'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

Comment: If this is a starter then don't apply the Spring Boot plugin. That plugin is only ment for packaging spring boot applications. Your starter generally doesn't contain code but only dependencies and thus a `pom.xml` and/or gradle dependency information.

Comment: Why would you like to remove ApiSpringBootStarterApplication? This class is the entry point for this application and it is required.

Comment: @ MariuszS because I create `spring-boot-starter`. I solved this problem, I create just gradle module instead spring-boot application

Answer (score 0):

Remove `org.springframework.boot` from plugins.
This plugin is aimed to build executable jar for your project. In case of starter you don't need to do this.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

By analogy, the same would be if you were using maven and `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score -2):

The JVM searching for the main class for start the application without the main class you can't start the application.

Why are you deleted the ApiSpringBootStarterApplication ?
Is your main class.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JVM, but with how the Spring Boot Plugin works.